# Fluent NHibernate ToFuture error in test environment but not in local development

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have some Fluent NHibernate code that runs fine on my local visual studio, but once it gets deployed to a test server I have the following error - one I've never come across before:

> Unable to cast object of type
>   'NHibernate.Impl.DelayedEnumerator`1[Core.FileLoad.File]' to type
>   'Remotion.Linq.QueryableBase`1[Core.FileLoad.File]'.

The code that causes this error is:

```
var files = _readRepository
.Query<File>()
.Where(f => f.Id == fileId)
.ToFuture();

_readRepository
.Query<Record>()
.Where(f => f.File.Id == fileId)
.ToFuture();

var file = files.ToList().First();
```

Comment: Which line exactly causes the exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ooops - the code I copied was not the actual code. There was a (Querybase) cast at the start also.
Once I removed that everything worked fine.

Thanks